# Exclude ie6 from a php include

Tags: php, internet-explorer-6

I have a script that works fine in all browsers except ie6 (including ie7 and ie8).
Is there any semi reliable way I can exclude this nefarious browser.

I've tried this:

```
<!--[if !IE 6]>
<?php include("fconditionals.php"); ?>
<![endif]-->
```

and this:

```
$user_agent = getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");
if (preg_match("MSIE 6", $user_agent)) 
{ 
include("fconditionals.php");
}
```

Comment: ...you have a *PHP script* that fails in IE?  PHP doesn't care about browsers.  What's going on, that a conditional comment isn't enough?

Comment: No - It's not the php script that fails in php - the php sets up conditionals for a jquery script that also doesn't fail in ie6 perse, but rather isn't as nice, and I'd prefer to add something else through css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you tried (Conditional Comments) won't work because the include is done on the server, while the page is being generated, and the conditional comments are only checked by the browser after the page has been downloaded.

The conditional comments will exclude the generated code from being displayed in IE6, but it will still be run by the server.

Additionally, the conditional comments in the format you've used them here will also exclude the code from being displayed by all non-IE browsers. If you only want to affect IE, you need to re-format it so that the other browsers don't treat the code inside as a comment, by using the `<![if !IE 6]>` syntax instead of `<!--[if !IE 6]>`.

That method still won't stop the code from being run on the server though.

The second method you tried is more likely to be closer to what you actually want to do. However, please note that although PHP does receive the `USER_AGENT` string, it is possible in most browsers to spoof the USER_AGENT, and some privacy/security products actively remove it, as do some web proxies. In other words, the USER_AGENT string is not a 100% reliable way of determining what browser someone is using.

That said, if you have specific PHP code that you want to exlude from being executed only for IE6, then it may be the only viable solution.

The reason this didn't work for you is that your code *includes* only IE6 rather than *excluding* it. You need to add a 'not' operator (`!`) in front of the `preg_match()`.

By the way: In your example code, you have `$user_agent = getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");`. It's worth pointing out that `$_SERVER['USER_AGENT']` is already available as a variable, you don't need to use getenv().

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would it be reliable to get or load the php through jquery, then use conditional statements on the js to exclude ie6? The final script is jquery so if the user didn't have jqueruy activated they wouldn't be able to see this effect anyway...

Comment: @Gertruder - To be honest, having read your comment above, your better option would be to do the browser detection in Javascript, and not do the conditional stuff in PHP at all. JQuery has a very good .browser method which you can use if you need certain code to run in specific browsers. PHP is not the best place to be doing that sort of thing.

Comment: Ok Thanks Spudly, I finally got it to work using: <!--[if !IE 6]><!-->
code  <!--<![endif]--> wrapped around the js code.

Answer (score 2):

The first version would never work. PHP only cares about `<?php ?>` pairs and utterly ignores anything outside of them. The IE conditional comments are only used by the browser, so the include would get executed on the server every time.

The second version has the logic reversed - you're including the file anytime IE6 is detected. you'd want `!preg_match` instead. However, remember that the user agent string is under user control and can be faked/hacked/subverted. There's no 100% reliable method of detecting the remote browser that can't be subverted somehow.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"MSIE 6") 
{ 
    include("fconditionals.php");
}
```